# Pull and push docker images without installed Docker

Tags: docker

We need to transfer large number of docker images from Azure DevOps to private container registry (this registry does not have access to the Internet). For this matter there is proxy machine with Windows Server with Azure Cli and access to the Azure DevOps, but we are restricted with installing Docker there.

Is there a way to pull docker images from Azure DevOps and push them into another container registry without installed Docker? Perhaps there is slim version of Docker or some official script.

Comment: no, you can not pull with out docker client. the way arround to keep the image in zip formate but will you still you will need docker to restore image from the zip

Comment: there is an option with save and load docker images via tar archives, but we wanted to avoid that approach

Comment: I think this is  total releavant question, there is another scenario for this, running a deployprocess and move an image from a private registry to a another (private/public) registry and doing this without a privileged docker in docker run. I'm mysqlf looking for a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

You can basically [save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) it as an archive, and reload it the same way.

Comment: docker save and docker load are the docker commands, therefore require docker to be installed

Comment: My bad : I though the problem was related with the networking problem and read too fast. But then : what is there any reason why the target and/or the source repo are not linked with some docker ? Is this for archiving matters? I don't see the purpose of storing an image in a repo that will not be used by docker

Comment: This is rather combination of the limitations - internal container registry and application servers with Docker will not have access to the internet, only proxy server will have. But there is strict limitation on the installed software of the proxy server. So I am looking for some small version of docker for pull and push of images (without need to have Hyper-V and other container features) or some Powershell/python script